# How can I remove “Listing #: ” from listings caption?

Tags: listings, captions

I am working on a C++ reference manual for myself and I want good-looking listings.

The Stack Overflow question entitled [LaTeX source code listing like in professional books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books) was very helpful but, for the life of me, I can't find anywhere on the Internet how to remove the "Listing #" part of the listing captions.

Below is a screenshot of what I have at the moment. I want to remove the front part of the listing caption; I don't want to remove the caption altogether, though, because I want to use it to show the name of the source file. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange! I've embedded the screenshot for you, which you'll be able to do yourself once you reach 10 reputation (almost there!).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books

Answer (score 17):

Use `title` instead of `caption` in the optional argument of the `lstlisting` environment. See p. 32 of the listings documentation for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=foo]
#include <iostream>
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[title=foo]
#include <iostream>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this is a very old comment, but I am experiencing a similar problem where this solution does not work. I gather it might be because of changes to updated packages. But if I use \begin{lstlisting}[title=foo]
#include <iostream>
\end{lstlisting}
My listing title will show as 
: foo
rather than just the title without a colon.

Answer (score 4):

The approach proposed by lockstep is straighforward, but your listings won't appear in the List of Listings if you follow it. If you want to avail of `\lstlistoflistings`, you'll need to use the `caption` key, not the `title` one.

In order not to print "Listing #: " in captions, simply remove `#1#2` from the third argument of `\DeclareCaptionFormat` in the code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742069) to the SO question entitled [LaTeX source code listing like in professional books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```